# Unable to get expected output for 2nd top test

Tags: arrays, perl, match

I would like my script to

- Extract each test name and convert the decimal value (from the `mrslt` line after the test name) from ITUFF
- Use the test name from ITUFF to find a matching a record in the MAP file and extract the ID and pin values
- Extract the modify token "AFC" from TPLFILE
- Use the ID to open the relevant IN file
- Open each IN file to extract output labels ("TDO_STROBE" ... "TDO_STROBE_9").
- Open each IN file again, replace all occurrences of "CTV" string with spaces. Put the modified file into a different directory leaving the original intact
- Print modify.txt file for every MODULE

For example, for MODULE_A, TEST_ABC is 2 bits and TDO_STROBE & TDO_STROBE_0 need to be assigned to them. TEST_BCD is 9 bits and TDO_STROBE_1 to TDO_STROBE_9 need to be assigned.

I managed to get the correct binary bit assigned to TDO_STROBE label for MODULE_A but the ID in $pat1[0] is wrong and also the subsequent bit assigned to TDO STROBE label for MODULE_B is messed up.

### Input files

#### ITUFF

```
2_tname_chuid
2_mrslt_3
0_tname_CKK_MODULE_A::TEST_ABC
0_mrslt_1
0_tname_CKK_MODULE_A::TEST_BCD
0_mrslt_451
0_tname_CKK_MODULE_B::TEST_EFG
0_mrslt_2
0_tname_CKK_MODULE_B::TEST_FEI
0_mrslt_405
```

#### MAP

```
Test,ID,Pin,Token
TEST_ABC,41534,TDO,AFC
TEST_BCD,41534,TDO,AFC
TEST_EFG,41532,GPIO_0,AFC
TEST_FEI,41532,GPIO_0,AFC
```

#### TPLFILE

```
Test PatModTest
{
    input_file = "~PATMO_PATH\\modify.txt";
    modify_token = "AFC";
}
```

*There are two IN files with different IDs in their filenames*

#### IN

```
#
TDO_STROBE:
NOP          
NOP          
NOP          
NOP       CTV
TDO_STROBE_0:
NOP          
NOP          
NOP          
NOP       CTV
TDO_STROBE_1:
NOP          
NOP          
NOP          
NOP       CTV
TDO_STROBE_2:
NOP          
NOP          
NOP          
NOP       CTV
TDO_STROBE_3:
NOP          
NOP          
NOP          
NOP       CTV
TDO_STROBE_4:
NOP          
NOP          
NOP          
NOP       CTV
TDO_STROBE_5:
NOP          
NOP          
NOP          
NOP       CTV
TDO_STROBE_6:
NOP          
NOP          
NOP          
NOP       CTV
TDO_STROBE_7:
NOP          
NOP          
NOP          
NOP       CTV
TDO_STROBE_8:
NOP          
NOP          
NOP          
NOP       CTV
TDO_STROBE_9:
```

### My Perl code

```
$ituf = <"*ituff*.txt">;
open( ITUFF, "<$ituf" ) || die "can't open the file";
while (<ITUFF>) {

    if ( $_ =~ /tname_CCK/ ) {

        @tname  = split /::/, $_;
        @tnameC = split /\n/, $tname[1];

        open( MAP, "<test_tupple.csv" ) || die "can't open the file";
        while (<MAP>) {
            @line = ( split ',', $_ );
            if ( $_ =~ /$tnameC[0]/ ) {
                push @test, $line[0];
            }
        }
    }
}
close ITUFF;
close MAP;


open( MAP, "<test_tupple.csv" ) || die "can't open the file";
while (<MAP>) {

    next if /^Test/;
    chomp;

    my @line = ( split ',', $_ );

    foreach $tn (@test) {

        if ( $line[0] eq $tn ) {
            $search = "found";
            push @test_map, $line[0];
            push @ID,       $line[1];
            push @pin,      $line[2];
        }
        else {
            $search = "not found";
        }
    }
}
close MAP;


$tpl = <"*CCK*.tpl">;
open( TPLFILE, "<$tpl" ) || die "can't open the file";
while (<TPLFILE>) {
    if ( $_ =~ /modify_token/ ) {
        @tpl_line0 = split /=/, $_;
        @tpl_line1 = split /;/, $tpl_line0[1];
        @tpl_line2 = split /"/, $tpl_line1[0];
    }
}
close TPLFILE;


$input = <"*@ID[$#ID]*.pat.data">;
@pat   = split /ALL.pat.data/, $input;
@pat1  = split /_/, $pat[0];
@tid   = split /C/, $pat1[0];


open( IN, "<$input" ) || die "can't open the file";
my $keyword = "CTV";
my $regex   = qr|\b($keyword)\b|;
while (<IN>) {

    next if /^#/;
    chomp;

    if ( $_ =~ /STROBE/ ) {
        @label = split /:/, $_;
        push @labelList, $label[0];
    }
    while (/$regex/g) {
        push @vectorLine, $.;
        $j = join ' ', @vectorLine;
        @vector = split /\s/, $j;
    }
}
close IN;


$d = $vector[1] - $vector[0] - 1;


my $replacestring = "CTV";
open( IN, "<$input" ) || die "can't open the file";
open( my $outfile, ">", "C:/Users/klee/Documents/perl/pat_heck/$pat[0]All.pat.data" ) || die "can't open the file";
while (<IN>) {
    $_ =~ s/$replacestring/   /g;
    print $outfile $_;
}
close IN;


open( ITUFF, "<$ituf" ) || die "can't open the file";
while (<ITUFF>) {
    foreach $tn (@test) {
        if ( $_ =~ /$tn/ ) {
            my $nextLine = <ITUFF>;
            @dec_res = split /_/, $nextLine;
            $bin_res = sprintf( "%02b", $dec_res[2] );
            push @bv, split //, $bin_res;
            $bitNum = ( $bin_res =~ tr/[0-1]// );
            push @totalBit, $bitNum;
        }
    }
}
close ITUFF;


foreach $b (@bv) {
    if ( $b == 0 ) {
        $tmap = "L";
    }
    else {
        $tmap = "H";
    }
    push @HL, $tmap;
}

for ( $t = 0; $t <= $#test; $t++ ) {
    push @test_iteration, $t;
}


open( OUT, ">modify.txt" ) || die "can't open the file";
foreach $ite (@test_iteration) {
    for (
        $i = $ite * $totalBit[ $ite - 1 ];
        $i < $totalBit[$ite] + $ite * $totalBit[ $ite - 1 ];
        $i++ )
    {
        print OUT "+ $tpl_line2[1] MAIN PAT $pat1[0]_$pat1[1]_$pat1[2]_$pat1[3]_$pat1[4]_*_$pat1[6]_$pat1[7]_$pat1[8]_$pat1[9]_$pat1[10]_$pat1[11]_$pat1[12] $labelList[$i] +$d DATA $pin[$ite] $HL[$i]\n";
    }
}
close OUT;


#checking use
for ( $i = 0; $i < $totalBit[0]; $i++ ) {

    #print "$test[$i] $labelList[$i]\n";
}

for ( $i = $totalBit[0]; $i <= $totalBit[1]; $i++ ) {

    #print "subsequent $labelList[$i]\n";
}
```

#### Expected output:

```
+ AFC MAIN PAT g0041534_B_n1604_CB0609a_dack_*_B_F_dfx_f_pp_h_count TDO_STROBE +4 DATA TDO L
+ AFC MAIN PAT g0041534_B_n1604_CB0609a_dack_*_B_F_dfx_f_pp_h_count TDO_STROBE_0 +4 DATA TDO H
+ AFC MAIN PAT g0041534_B_n1604_CB0609a_dack_*_B_F_dfx_f_pp_h_count TDO_STROBE_1 +4 DATA TDO H
+ AFC MAIN PAT g0041534_B_n1604_CB0609a_dack_*_B_F_dfx_f_pp_h_count TDO_STROBE_2 +4 DATA TDO H
+ AFC MAIN PAT g0041534_B_n1604_CB0609a_dack_*_B_F_dfx_f_pp_h_count TDO_STROBE_3 +4 DATA TDO H
+ AFC MAIN PAT g0041534_B_n1604_CB0609a_dack_*_B_F_dfx_f_pp_h_count TDO_STROBE_4 +4 DATA TDO L
+ AFC MAIN PAT g0041534_B_n1604_CB0609a_dack_*_B_F_dfx_f_pp_h_count TDO_STROBE_5 +4 DATA TDO L
+ AFC MAIN PAT g0041534_B_n1604_CB0609a_dack_*_B_F_dfx_f_pp_h_count TDO_STROBE_6 +4 DATA TDO L
+ AFC MAIN PAT g0041534_B_n1604_CB0609a_dack_*_B_F_dfx_f_pp_h_count TDO_STROBE_7 +4 DATA TDO L
+ AFC MAIN PAT g0041534_B_n1604_CB0609a_dack_*_B_F_dfx_f_pp_h_count TDO_STROBE_8 +4 DATA TDO H
+ AFC MAIN PAT g0041534_B_n1604_CB0609a_dack_*_B_F_dfx_f_pp_h_count TDO_STROBE_9 +4 DATA TDO H
+ AFC MAIN PAT g0041532_B_n1604_CB0609a_dack_*_B_F_dfx_f_pp_h_count TDO_STROBE +4 DATA GPIO_0 H
+ AFC MAIN PAT g0041532_B_n1604_CB0609a_dack_*_B_F_dfx_f_pp_h_count TDO_STROBE_0 +4 DATA GPIO_0 L
+ AFC MAIN PAT g0041532_B_n1604_CB0609a_dack_*_B_F_dfx_f_pp_h_count TDO_STROBE_1 +4 DATA GPIO_0 H
+ AFC MAIN PAT g0041532_B_n1604_CB0609a_dack_*_B_F_dfx_f_pp_h_count TDO_STROBE_2 +4 DATA GPIO_0 H
+ AFC MAIN PAT g0041532_B_n1604_CB0609a_dack_*_B_F_dfx_f_pp_h_count TDO_STROBE_3 +4 DATA GPIO_0 L
+ AFC MAIN PAT g0041532_B_n1604_CB0609a_dack_*_B_F_dfx_f_pp_h_count TDO_STROBE_4 +4 DATA GPIO_0 L
+ AFC MAIN PAT g0041532_B_n1604_CB0609a_dack_*_B_F_dfx_f_pp_h_count TDO_STROBE_5 +4 DATA GPIO_0 H
+ AFC MAIN PAT g0041532_B_n1604_CB0609a_dack_*_B_F_dfx_f_pp_h_count TDO_STROBE_6 +4 DATA GPIO_0 L
+ AFC MAIN PAT g0041532_B_n1604_CB0609a_dack_*_B_F_dfx_f_pp_h_count TDO_STROBE_7 +4 DATA GPIO_0 H
+ AFC MAIN PAT g0041532_B_n1604_CB0609a_dack_*_B_F_dfx_f_pp_h_count TDO_STROBE_8 +4 DATA GPIO_0 L
+ AFC MAIN PAT g0041532_B_n1604_CB0609a_dack_*_B_F_dfx_f_pp_h_count TDO_STROBE_9 +4 DATA GPIO_0 H
```

#### Actual output:

```
+ AFC MAIN PAT g0041532_B_n1604_CB0609a_dack_*_B_F_dfx_f_pp_h_count TDO_STROBE +4 DATA TDO L
+ AFC MAIN PAT g0041532_B_n1604_CB0609a_dack_*_B_F_dfx_f_pp_h_count TDO_STROBE_0 +4 DATA TDO H
+ AFC MAIN PAT g0041532_B_n1604_CB0609a_dack_*_B_F_dfx_f_pp_h_count TDO_STROBE_1 +4 DATA TDO H
+ AFC MAIN PAT g0041532_B_n1604_CB0609a_dack_*_B_F_dfx_f_pp_h_count TDO_STROBE_2 +4 DATA TDO H
+ AFC MAIN PAT g0041532_B_n1604_CB0609a_dack_*_B_F_dfx_f_pp_h_count TDO_STROBE_3 +4 DATA TDO H
+ AFC MAIN PAT g0041532_B_n1604_CB0609a_dack_*_B_F_dfx_f_pp_h_count TDO_STROBE_4 +4 DATA TDO L
+ AFC MAIN PAT g0041532_B_n1604_CB0609a_dack_*_B_F_dfx_f_pp_h_count TDO_STROBE_5 +4 DATA TDO L
+ AFC MAIN PAT g0041532_B_n1604_CB0609a_dack_*_B_F_dfx_f_pp_h_count TDO_STROBE_6 +4 DATA TDO L
+ AFC MAIN PAT g0041532_B_n1604_CB0609a_dack_*_B_F_dfx_f_pp_h_count TDO_STROBE_7 +4 DATA TDO L
+ AFC MAIN PAT g0041532_B_n1604_CB0609a_dack_*_B_F_dfx_f_pp_h_count TDO_STROBE_8 +4 DATA TDO H
+ AFC MAIN PAT g0041532_B_n1604_CB0609a_dack_*_B_F_dfx_f_pp_h_count TDO_STROBE_9 +4 DATA TDO H
+ AFC MAIN PAT g0041532_B_n1604_CB0609a_dack_*_B_F_dfx_f_pp_h_count  +4 DATA GPIO_0 L
+ AFC MAIN PAT g0041532_B_n1604_CB0609a_dack_*_B_F_dfx_f_pp_h_count  +4 DATA GPIO_0 H
+ AFC MAIN PAT g0041532_B_n1604_CB0609a_dack_*_B_F_dfx_f_pp_h_count TDO_STROBE_5 +4 DATA GPIO_0 L
+ AFC MAIN PAT g0041532_B_n1604_CB0609a_dack_*_B_F_dfx_f_pp_h_count TDO_STROBE_6 +4 DATA GPIO_0 L
+ AFC MAIN PAT g0041532_B_n1604_CB0609a_dack_*_B_F_dfx_f_pp_h_count TDO_STROBE_7 +4 DATA GPIO_0 L
+ AFC MAIN PAT g0041532_B_n1604_CB0609a_dack_*_B_F_dfx_f_pp_h_count TDO_STROBE_8 +4 DATA GPIO_0 H
+ AFC MAIN PAT g0041532_B_n1604_CB0609a_dack_*_B_F_dfx_f_pp_h_count TDO_STROBE_9 +4 DATA GPIO_0 H
+ AFC MAIN PAT g0041532_B_n1604_CB0609a_dack_*_B_F_dfx_f_pp_h_count  +4 DATA GPIO_0 H
+ AFC MAIN PAT g0041532_B_n1604_CB0609a_dack_*_B_F_dfx_f_pp_h_count  +4 DATA GPIO_0 L
+ AFC MAIN PAT g0041532_B_n1604_CB0609a_dack_*_B_F_dfx_f_pp_h_count  +4 DATA GPIO_0 H
+ AFC MAIN PAT g0041532_B_n1604_CB0609a_dack_*_B_F_dfx_f_pp_h_count  +4 DATA GPIO_0 H
```

Comment: create simplifed question, it is hard to understand what you doing,

Comment: 1) Extract MODULE_A info in ITUFF: TEST_ABC, TEST_BCD, 1 & 451 (in binary format). 2) Extract ID & pin if found TEST_ABC & TEST_BCD in MAP file. 3) Extract 'modify token', AFC from TPLFILE. 4) search for the relevant IN file(s) with filename contain ID. 5) Extract label (TDO_STROBE - TDO_STROBE_9) from IN file. 10) print "+ modify token IN filename +vector line DATA pin tmap\n". Repeat step 1-10 for MODULE_B. Example: for MODULE_A, TEST_ABC is 2 bit and TDO_STROBE & TDO_STROBE_0 are assigned. Meanwhile TEST_BCD is 9 bit and TDO_STROBE_1.. TDO_STROBE_9 are assigned. Can anyone help?

Comment: Simplify, you want us just to debug your program ?

Comment: My script need to read a few files and get info from each file and lastly print to a file in certain requirement. When I remove MODULE_B related lines from ITUFF, I manage to get the correct print out. However, the print out become erroneous if there is more than 1 MODULE in ituff. I need some help to correct my script.

Comment: Yes, debug. It is against rules. Just create the simple version of your script, and try to show where your problem, to debug perl programs use tools

Comment: You say:  " .. for MODULE_A, TEST_ABC is 2 bit" - Why?    You say:  "TEST_BCD is 9 bit " - Why?  I can't see the digit "9" anywhere?

Comment: @Marty: The data in the ITUFF file for `TEST_BCD` says `0_mrslt_451`. 451 in binary is 111000011, which has nine bits. That's where the 9 comes from. Yeah I know; freaky right?

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid there's a lot wrong with your code, and the main problem is that your thinking isn't very clear. You also appear to have written the whole program before you started testing it, which, as you have found, leaves an enormous amount of debugging to do with no foundation

You should write no more than three or four lines of code at a time and test those before you proceed. That way you will never build a mountain of debugging to do, and you will always have confidence in the most recent version of your program

Some other guidelines

- You should *always* `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` at the top of *every* Perl program that you write. You will also need to declare all the variables that you use, which should be done as *late as possible* in the code and not in a big block at the start of the file
- You should use *lexical file handles* with the *three-parameter version of `open`*. You can also `use autodie` at the top of your program, which will check many Perl IO operations for you so that you don't have to do it manually

  For instance

  ```
  open(MAP,"<test_tupple.csv")||die "can't open the file";
  ```

  is better (with `autodie` in place) like this

  ```
  open my $map_fh, '<', 'test_tupple.csv';
  ```

There are a number of other issues, but I don't want to overwhelm you. The two points above are by far the most important

Now for the bugs

- You say your ITUFF file contains lines like

  ```
  0_tname_CKK_MODULE_A::TEST_ABC
  ```

  but you are testing them with the statement

  ```
  if ( $_ =~ /tname_CCK/ ) {
  ```

  which will never match
- Your calculations for the iteration range in the output `for` loop are wrong. You have this

  ```
  for $ite (@test_iteration) {
      for (
          $i = $ite * $totalBit[ $ite - 1 ];
          $i < $totalBit[$ite] + $ite * $totalBit[ $ite - 1 ];
          $i++ ) {

          print OUT "+ $tpl_line2[1] MAIN PAT $pat1[0]_$pat1[1]_$pat1[2]_$pat1[3]_$pat1[4]_*_$pat1[6]_$pat1[7]_$pat1[8]_$pat1[9]_$pat1[10]_$pat1[11]_$pat1[12] $labelList[$i] +$d DATA $pin[$ite] $HL[$i]\n";
      }
  }
  ```

which should be something like this

```
    for $ite (@test_iteration) {

        my $start = 0;
        $start += $_ for @total_bit[ 0 .. $ite - 1 ];

        for my $i ( $start .. $start + $totalBit[$ite] - 1 ) {

            print ...;
        }
    }
```

- Finally, you your data results in 22 lines of output (the total number of bits to represent the `mrslt` numbers in the ITUFF) but there are only 11 items in `@label_list` (obtained from the lines that contain `STROBE` in the IN file). That means only the first 11 lines of output have a field like `TDO_STROBE_9` etc. This is blank in the last 11

  I can't suggest what the solution to this should be as I know nothing about your data and it's impossible to know where the missing values should come from

I hope this helps you on your way

Comment: Why won't `if ( $_ =~ /tname_CCK/ ) {` match when tested against the string `0_tname_CKK_MODULE_A::TEST_ABC` ?  Or... how am I misunderstanding what you are saying?

Comment: @Marty: `CCK` vs. `CKK`

Comment: Sorry about that :-)

Comment: @Marty: Easily overlooked!